# Pre-populating lookup Account name into a new Contact from Lead's Company

Tags: visualforce

We have a client who has a VisualForce page in order to convert the leads into contacts. But there are some issues in the form.

- For instance we need the field Lead's company should be prefilled into the lookup contact's account name.
- Also we want to add some other filters in the standard searching lookup which are another Lead's custom fields like the Company Address in order to reduce the searching set.

So, based on [this](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000ghPqAAI), I think It's likely possible without the need of creation of an extra visual force page and just using the standard lookup searching page.
Can someone give me ideas how to achieve this in order to reach the best solution without the need to reinvent the wheel?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we decided to create a new visual force page and don't try any hack.